# What would happen on earth if there was a surge in gravitational waves

Tags: black-hole, gravitational-waves, neutron-star

There are claims that when massive objects merge some of their mass is converted to gravitational energy. Such as the following links:

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/38727/2305

https://youtu.be/FtYwsw3hefc

What kind of macro effects, if any, could be perceived by a person with their senses without instruments if sufficiently large gravitational waves happened to hit earth, in the case of a ripple and in the case of a long term constant change (if that's even a thing, otherwise please assume a very very low frequency, which would mean a gentle slope).

What would be an example of the distances and masses involved for us to feel such effect?

Comment: If close, I'd expect gamma rays and such to do us in long before the planet got shredded by Gravitational distortions.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger good point. But I'm really curious to grasp what's the effect of gravity waves interacting with everyday objects at a human scale. For example, what amount of energy could cause, say, a 1C increase in oceans water leading to global warming, ,if that were to be the dominant effect. So looking back, I'd need to rephrase the title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How far should the source be, for the gravitation waves to be visible on Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/how-far-should-the-source-be-for-the-gravitation-waves-to-be-visible-on-earth)

Comment: Note: the actual dislocation of an average gravitational wave is a thousands of a nucleus.

Comment: Related question in Physics SE: [How would a passing gravitational wave look or feel?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338912/83380) with four long, disparate answers :-)